# JQuery Multicheckbox value in ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, checkbox

I have issue with getting value of checkbox in ajax data it shows undefined variable.
I use below checkboxes, I get value in alert but it does not pass in ajax

```
<input type="checkbox" name="tick_if_apply[]" id="NEA"  value=""  class="tick_if_apply">
<input type="checkbox" name="tick_if_apply[]" id="CCJ"  class="tick_if_apply" value="6years">
```

Here is my code

```
<script>
$na= jQuery.noConflict();
$na(document).ready(function(){ 
$na('.continue_btn').click(function(){
 var title=$na("#title").val();
var firnstname=$na("#firnstname").val();
var lastname=$na("#lastname").val();
var dob=$na("#dob").val();
var gender=$na("#gender").val();
var addr1=$na("#addr1").val();
var addr2=$na("#addr2").val();
var addr3=$na("#addr3").val();
var city=$na("#city").val();
var country=$na("#country").val();
var pcode =$na("#pcode").val();
var region=$na("#region").val();
var adyears=$na("#adyears").val();
var admonths=$na("#admonths").val();
var livingstatus=$na("#livingstatus").val();
var qualification=$na("#qualification").val();
var empstatus=$na("#empstatus").val();
var visadate=$na("#visadate").val();
var exforce=$na("#exforce").val();
var crmrecord=$na("#crmrecord").val();
var hwsmloan=$na("#hwsmloan").val();
var appforloan=$na("#appforloan").val();

  $na('.tick_if_apply:checked').each(function(){
         var tick_if_apply=$na(this).val();
         alert(tick_if_apply);

    });


             $na.ajax({
                         type: "POST",
                         url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/app_process.php',
                 data: 'title='+title+'&firnstname='+firnstname+'&lastname='+lastname+'&dob='+dob+'&gender='+gender+'&addr1='+addr1+'&addr2='+addr2+
                '&addr3='+addr3+'&city='+city+'&country='+country+'&pcode='+pcode+'&region='+region+'&adyears='+adyears+'&admonths='+admonths+'&livingstatus='+livingstatus+
                '&qualification='+qualification+'&empstatus='+empstatus+'&visadate='+visadate+'&exforce='+exforce+'&crmrecord='+crmrecord+'&hwsmloan='+hwsmloan+'&appforloan='+appforloan+'&tick_if_apply='+tick_if_apply,

                         cache: false,
                         success: function(result){ alert(result);}

                                       });
                }); 
 });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There has to be an easier way to get that data to the serverside, I'd suggest adding a common class (like `.ajax_elements`) to all the elements you're trying to get the value of, and then iterating over those elements and getting the ID and the value.

To get the value of all ticked checkboxes, iterate and store the values in an array, and send them with the data object :

```
jQuery(function($){ 
    var data  = {},
        ticks = [];

    $('.ajax_elements').each(function(_, elem) {
        data[this.id] = this.value;
    });

    $('.tick_if_apply').each(function(_, tick) {
        if (this.checked) ticks.push(this.value);
    });

    data['tick_if_apply'] = ticks;

    $.ajax({
        type  : 'POST',
        url   : '<?php bloginfo('template_url')?>/app_process.php',
        data  : data,
        cache : false
    }).done(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: hi thanks,i have a question that if i use ajax_elements to all my elements instead of taking id of each is that possible to get all datas? if this works this would be awesome...thanks

Comment: hi can you please reply??

Comment: Just add the class to all the elements, but don't remove the ID's, and it does the same thing but you don't have to target each element individually

Comment: hi adeneo i need one help,i am having issue with file upload using ajax,i dont get data in php $_FILES,can i write something in existing code so that file upload can also work with same code...Thanks.

Comment: @vishal - You can't really upload files directly with ajax, you'll have to look into the formData object and search stack overflow for examples, and for older browsers it gets a bit complicated with iframes and stuff as fallbacks.

Comment: hi but i have used the code you gave which work fine.so how do i integrate separate file uploading with your code...

Comment: File uploads are more complicated, you can still use the above, but you have to somehow add the [**formData**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Web%2FAPI%2FFormData%2FUsing_FormData_Objects) for the files, and that only works for newer browsers, older browsers don't support file uploads with ajax at all. This is why plugins like jQuery file uploader is so popular, it's hard to get right on your own.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41547/discussion-between-vishal-and-adeneo)